# Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting second monitor connected via VGA

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors

The issue started after I used my ubuntu hard-drive on other pc, now secondary monitor plugged on VGA stopped to work. I Tried most of the solutions present on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), but nothing is fine for my issue.

```
lshw -c video
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:37 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

I think the issue could be in some file settings, indeed while I was try to start ubuntu from bootable USB hard-drive, secondary monitor started to work.
How can I to fix it?
Thanks in advance.